# libtiff with VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use libtiff 4.0.3 on VS2012 x64, and I got error for my code:

**Here is the code:**

```
long SaveTIFF(wchar_t *filePathAndName, char * pMemoryBuffer, long width, long height)
{
    TIFF *out= TIFFOpenW(filePathAndName, "w"); 
        ret TURE;
}
```

**Here is the rror:**

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TIFFOpenW referenced in function "long __cdecl SaveTIFF(wchar_t *,char *,long,long)" (?SaveTIFF@@YAJPEA_WPEADJJ@Z)
```

**Here is what I have done:**

1. Download libtiff 4.0.3, and compile it to generate libraries. Everything needed/generated(.h, .lib, .dll, ...) is in D:\myProject|tools\libtiff\ folder.
2. Open VS2012 and start a new C++ dll project
3. Project > Properties > C/C++ > Additional Include Directories, added
   "D:\myProject|tools\libtiff\"
4. Project > Properties > Linker > Additional library directories, added
   "D:\myProject|tools\libtiff\"
5. Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, added
   libtiff.lib
6. In my .cpp file, added #include "tiff.h" and #include "tiffio.h"

Finally, my code generation is *Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)*

I don't know what else I should do. Anyone has any idea how I can make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the visuall studio' own native x64 command window to build libtiff for VS x64 application.

Comment: Awesome. You are right. libtiff built with x64 VS command console, problem gone. Thanks.